# Моргающее в панели задач окно

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

Подскажите пожалуйста как заставить окно моргать в панели задач? Ну так часто делают типа какое то событие в окне произошло, а оно свернуто и вот такое извещение.

@VladD хз я может что то не так делаю, но у меня никак не хочет это работать. Я ставил точку останова у меня при попытке создать экземпляр WindowInteropHelper выходит из функции вообще. Тестирую вот так:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var t = new Timer(5000);
        t.Elapsed += Elapsed;
        t.Start();
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern int FlashWindow(IntPtr Hwnd, bool Revert);

    private void Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        var hwnd = new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle;
        FlashWindow(hwnd, true);
    }
}
```

Comment: А просто `window.Activate()` не покатит? (Окно при это должно быть в фоне.)

Comment: @VladD чет ничего от вызова этой функции не происходит.

Comment: А окно при этом в фоне?

Comment: @VladD что значит в фоне? Свернуто? Да свернуто.

Comment: Точнее наверное я имел ввиду моргание не в трее, а в панели задач. Немного перепутал понятия.

Comment: Обновил ответ, проверяйте.

Answer (score 4):

Попробуйте так:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern int FlashWindow(IntPtr Hwnd, bool Revert);

// ...
var hwnd = new WindowInteropHelper(window).Handle;
FlashWindow(hwnd, true);
```

---

Вызывать эту функцию на таймере не стоит, т. к. он доставляет сообщения в непонятно какой поток. Используйте `DispatcherTimer`, он выполняет события в главном потоке:

```
var dt = new DispatcherTimer();
dt.Tick += (s, e) =>
    {
        dt.Stop();
        var hwnd = new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle;
        FlashWindow(hwnd, true);
    };
dt.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
dt.Start();
```